# Link going to last scroll position instead of anchor

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, gatsby

On my React app, I have two pages: page A, the home page, and page B.
On page B, I have links that go to page A in a specific section.

On page A:
`<section id="foo">Foo</section>`
On page B:
`<a href="/#foo">Go to foo</a>`

Every time I go to page B from page A and click on the link, the screen goes to the last scroll position and not the section.

I tried to deactivate the browser scroll history function with:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (history.scrollRestoration) {
    history.scrollRestoration = 'manual';
  }
}, []);
```

I also to tried to add function to go to desired section:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (window.location.hash) {
      const anchor = document.querySelector(window.location.hash);
      anchor.scrollIntoView();
  }
}, []);
```

But none of these solutions works. I reproduce the same behaviour on Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a Gatsby feature: it overrides the browser default scroll history behaviour. More info there https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/routing/scroll-restoration/

I fixed it by adding:

```js
// gatsby-browser.js
exports.shouldUpdateScroll = ({
  routerProps: { location },
  getSavedScrollPosition,
}) => {
  return location.href.indexOf("#") > -1 ? false : true;
};
```